# Referencing Assemblies. Command-line compilation

Tags: .net, command-line, assemblies

I am using the jsc.exe compiler that comes with the .Net Framework for compiling my JScript.Net scripts into executables. What is the right way to reference assemblies from the command line? I keep getting "the referenced assembly could not be found" errors so I must be doing something wrong.

This is what I tried:

```
jsc.exe /reference:System.Web.Dll MyScript.jsn
jsc.exe /reference:System.Web.Dll /lib:C:\Windows\assembly MyScript.jsn
jsc.exe /reference:System.Web.Dll /lib:C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32 MyScript.jsn
```

Comment: okay I got it working by just using the jsc.exe that comes with version 2.x of the .Net framework. No Idea why it would not work with the one that comes with the more recent 4.x version of .Net.